# deleting and creating new RTP streams after event loop started

Tags: c++, live555

I'm using Live555 to stream 1 or more video streams. Following the example of testH264VideoStreamer.cpp, various objects are created, and then an event loop is started. Here's an excerpt from my initialization code that handles creation of objects for a single video stream:

```
// Setup usage environment
this->scheduler = BasicTaskScheduler::createNew();
this->env = BasicUsageEnvironment::createNew(*scheduler);

// Setup framed source
this->framedSource = H264FramedSource::createNew(*this->env, 0, 0);
this->discreteFramer = H264VideoStreamDiscreteFramer::createNew(*env, framedSource);

// Setup sockets
this->rtpGroupsock = new Groupsock(
        *this->env,
        this->destinationAddress,
        this->rtpPort,
        this->ttl);

this->rtcpGroupsock = new Groupsock(
        *this->env,
        this->destinationAddress,
        this->rtcpPort,
        this->ttl);

this->videoSink = H264VideoRTPSink::createNew(
        *this->env,
        this->rtpGroupsock,
        DEF_RTP_PT);

this->rtcp = RTCPInstance::createNew(
        *this->env,
        this->rtcpGroupsock,
        DEF_SESSION_BW,
        cname,
        videoSink,
        0,                   // We are a server
        True);               // We are an SSM source
// Create RTSP server
this->rtspServer = RTSPServer::createNew(*this->env, rtsp_port);
this->sms = ServerMediaSession::createNew(
        *this->env, "test",
        ip.c_str(),
        0,
        True);
this->sms->addSubsession(PassiveServerMediaSubsession::createNew(
        *this->videoSink,
        this->rtcp));
this->rtspServer->addServerMediaSession(this->sms);
this->videoSink->startPlaying(*this->discreteFramer, 0, this->videoSink);
this->env->taskScheduler().doEventLoop();
```

So my question is: suppose I wanted my environment/scheduler to handle events for a 2nd video stream, or I wanted to delete the existing stream. I see that I can add an argument to `doEventLoop()` to allow the event loop to exit. Then I can clean up an old stream, start new streams, and restart the event loop.  Is it possible to do these operations once the event loop has already been started? Would stopping and restarting the stream interrupt existing sessions? (and thus I should use a different thread its own scheduler/env for each video stream?)

Answer (score 0):

When the event loop is running you can do actions in almost 2 different ways :

- using a trigger from an other thread
- using a scheduled task

**Using trigger from an other thread**

1. Implement an event callback to do the work

> ```
>  static void eventCallback(void* clientData) {
>   ....
>  }
> ```

2. Register your event callback:

> `int triggerId = this->scheduler->createEventTrigger(eventCallback);`

3. Call the trigger when you need :

> `this->scheduler->triggerEvent(m_eventTriggerId, this);`

**Using a scheduled task**

1. Create a Task callback

> ```
> static void TaskCallback(void* clientData) { 
>   ...
> }
> ```

2. Schedule it before running the eventloop:

> `this->scheduler->scheduleDelayedTask(1000000, TaskCallback, this);`

In static callbacks you can redirect to your class instance using the clientData that contains the this pointer.